# tkinter option menu doesn't execute callback function for option created via .add_command(label='New Item')

Tags: python, tkinter

My very first tkinter experience was going rather smoothly, but now I'm stumped.

I grabbed some code I saw on another thread, and added a 'New Item'. I can see that the callback function isn't executed when 'New Item' is selected. StrVar isn't updated for 'New Item' as it is for the initial items. If StrVar did update, then I wouldn't need the callback function.

I have tried to resolve this using .__setit(), .trace_add(), callback functions, as well as some .configure stuff. What am I missing? I need for the user to be able to see the item they selected.

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(selection):
    print(selection)

root = tk.Tk()
options = tk.StringVar()
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, options, 'a', 'b', 'c', command=callback)
menu.pack()
menu['menu'].add_command(label='New Item')
options.set('a')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `command=callback` to `.add_command(label="New Item")`?

Comment: @TheLizzard you are too fast :(

Comment: @TkinterLover :D my approach would have raised an error... So I don't consider mine as an answer

Comment: @hilton8r Look at the comment that I posted on the answer

Comment: Thank you both! I tried so many variations that were probably close. I think I missed tying the callback function to 'New Item' in conjunction with passing the variable to the callback function in the wrong place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the command for every option you add. Additionally, you need to add `options.set(selection)` at the end to make sure the "New Item" options is selected.

**Code:**

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(selection):
    print(selection)
    options.set(selection)

root = tk.Tk()
options = tk.StringVar()
menu = tk.OptionMenu(root, options, 'a', 'b', 'c', command=callback)
menu.pack()
menu['menu'].add_command(label='New Item', command=lambda: callback('New Item'))
options.set('a')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: When I was testing it and I clicked on `"New Item"` it didn't change the option in the GUI for some reason. You might want to add `options.set(selection)` at the end of `callback`

Comment: I have no idea why you need that or how `tk.OptionMenu` works. I always just use `tk.Menu`

Comment: @TkinterLover I asked a new question because I couldn't get this working in my project. The only difference is adding the options one by one vs adding the options from a for loop. Hoping you and TheLizzard can take a peek. New to  stack overflow, so trying to figure out tagging etc...